# LinkedList with Serialization in Java

Tags: java, mysql, serialization, linked-list

I'm getting introduced to serialization and ran into some problems when pairing it with `LinkedList`

Consider i have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE JAVA_OBJECTS   (
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    OBJ_NAME VARCHAR(50),
    OBJ_VALUE BLOB
);
```

And i'm planning to store 3 object types - so the table may look like so -

```
ID  OBJ_NAME    OBJ_VALUE
============================
1   Class1      BLOB
2   Class2      BLOB
3   Class1      BLOB
4   Class3      BLOB
5   Class3      BLOB
```

And i'll use 3 different `LinkedList`'s to manage these objects..

I've been able to implement `LoadFromTable()` and `StoreIntoTable(Class1 obj1)`.
My question is - if i change an attribute for a `Class2` object in `LinkedList<Class2>`, how do i effect the change in the DB for this individual item? Also take into account that the order of the elements in `LinkedList` may change..

Thanks : )

* EDIT
Yes, i understand that i'll have to delete/update a row in my DB table. But how do i keep track of WHICH row to update? I'm only storing the objects in the List, not their respective IDs in the table.

Comment: Do you actually have DB? Or you are using LinkedLists to store the data?

Comment: In Java, a `Collection` is serializable if the classes it contains are serializable.

Comment: @athena, yes - i'm using mysql.

Comment: Do you want to keep your objects sorted by the ID? Or by the order in which they where added?

Comment: It doesn't matter, but let's say - by ID?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to store their IDs in the objects you are storing. However, I would suggest not trying to roll your own ORM system, and instead use something like Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

If you change an attribute in a an object or the order of items.  You will have to delete that row and insert the updated list again.

Comment: and how do i know WHICH row to delete?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood part of the question.  Why aren't you just saving the 3 lists to the database instead of break the list item out and saving them individually.  (How are you loading them back in?)

Comment: Are you suggesting i serialize the lists themselves into the database?

Comment: Yes.  It will greatly simplify your saving and loading.  I am assuming there is no value to you on the database side to break it up.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong here - but if i store a list into the DB - am i storing only the references to the objects? Or the objects as well?

Comment: @wretrOvian - Serializing a Collection also serializes all of its members.

Answer (score 0):

```
How do i effect the change in the DB for this individual item?
```

I hope I get you right. The SQL update and delete statements allow you to add a WHERE clause in which you chose the ID of the row to update.

e.g.

```
UPDATE JAVA_OBJECTS  SET OBJ_NAME ="new name" WHERE ID = 2
```

EDIT:

To prevent problems with your Ids you could wrap you object

```
class Wrapper {
   int  dbId;
   Object obj;
}
```

And add them instead of the 'naked' object into your LinkedList

Comment: I think i was ambiguous in phrasing - How do i know which ID to put in? Like i said - i have my objects in the List, but not their respective IDs - what if the order of my List changes - which all rows do i apply changes to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AUTO_INCREMENT attribute](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for your table and then use the [mysql_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html) function to retrieve the id assigned to the row added/updated by the last INSERT/UPDATE statement. Along with this maintain a map (eg a HashMap) from the java object to the Id. Using this map you can keep track of which row to delete/update.

**Edit:** See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76254/access-to-auto-increment-identity-field-after-sql-insert-in-java) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem here is, that you mix and match different levels of abstraction. By storing serialized Java objects into a relational database as BLOBs you have to consider several drawbacks:

- You loose interoperability. Applications written in other languages than Java are not able to read the data back. Even other Java applications have to have the class files of the serialized classes in their classpath.
- Changing the class definitions of the stored classes will end up in maintenance nightmares.
- You give up the advantages of a relational database. Serialization hides the actual data from the database. So the database is presented only with a black box. You are unable to execute any meaningfull query against the real data. All what you have is the ID and block of bytes.
- You have to implement low level data handling by yourself. Actually the database is made to handle your data effectively, but because of serialization you hinder it doing its job. So you are on your own and you are running into that problem right now.

So in most cases you benifit from [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and using the right tool for a job.

Here are some suggestions:

Separate the internal data handling inside your application from persistent storage. Design your database schema in a way to enable the built-in database features to handle the data efficently. In case of a relational database like MySQL you can choose from different technologies like plain JDBC, object relational mappers like JPA or simple mappers like MyBatis. Separation here means to avoid to contaminate the database with implementation specific concerns.

If you have for example in your Java application a List of Person instances and each Person consists of a name and an age. Then you would represent that list in a relational database as a table consisting of a VARCHAR field for the name and a numeric field for the age and maybe a third field for a unique key. Then the database is able to do what it can do best: managing large amounts of data.

Inside your application you typically separate the persistent layer from the rest of your program containing the code to communicate with the database.

In some use cases a relational database may not be the appropiate tool. Maybe in a single user desktop application with a small set of data it may be the best to simply serialize your Person list into a plain file and read it back at the next start up.

But there exists other alternatives to persist your data. Maybe some kind of object oriented database is the right tool. In particular I have experiences with Fast Objects. As a simplification it is serialization on steroids. There is no need for a layer like JPA or JDBC between your application and your database. You are able to store the class instances directly into the database. But unlike the relational database with its BLOB field, the OODB knows your classes and the actual data and can benefit from that.

Another alternative may be [JDBM](http://jdbm.sourceforge.net/) or [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html).

So separation of concerns and choosing the right persistence strategy (and using it the right way) is a key concern for the success of your project. But doing it right is hard even for experienced developers.